# What permissions are required to print to a locally attached shared printer?

Tags: windows-xp, permissions, printer, administrator

I have several users who have to be a local admin on a PC because that PC has a printer locally attached to it. Apparently they cannot print to it unless they are local admins. I really would like to remove them from that group, is there any way around this? They are all using XP in a 2003 domain environment, but the printer is not networkable so we can't add it to our print server.

Comment: Just FYI, there are [dedicated print servers](http://www.amazon.com/b?ie=UTF8&node=13983761) that allow you make a printer *networkable*. They are relatively cheap (~40USD maybe). In case you haven't looked into that option yet.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to right-click on the local printer in Printers & Faxes, choose properties and adjust the permissions to it on the security tab.

I don't have a XP machine handy at the moment but it may just be a case of adding the "Users" (or XP equivalent) group and giving it full access to the printer.

Comment: I agree that that should work, but it didn't seem to.

Comment: Are the accounts domain users? If so add the domain users group to the permissions.

Comment: I'm building 2 PCs to replicate this problem, I'll post back after I test that but I know that "Everyone" had permissions and a domain group that they were in.

Comment: Ok after a default installation adding the printer and printing to it was fine. However after I removed everyone and only allowed admins to print, I was able to add a nonadmin user and still print to it. So as far as I can tell the security tab on the printer is useless.